# What does the X mean in hexadecimal character codes for HTML?

Tags: html, character-encoding, hex, character-codes

The format for a hexadecimal character code in HTML is:

> `&#x00;`

... where `00` is the UTF-8 or ASCII code of the character.

Obviously the `&` and the `;` are somewhat arbitrary codes, and the `#` indicates that a numerical code is being given rather than a text reference like `&amp;` for ampersand. Without the `x`, the browser expects a code in decimal format, which makes sense.

But why the `x` to indicate hexidecimal?

Answer (score -1):

x means that is hexadecimal reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_dingbats.asp